# Calculate percentages of occurrences by rolling window in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have the following pyspark dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
foo = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2],
                    'time': [1,2,3,4,5, 1,2,3,4,5],
                    'value': ['a','a','a','b','b', 'b','b','c','c','c']})

foo_df = spark.createDataFrame(foo)
foo_df.show()

+---+----+-----+
| id|time|value|
+---+----+-----+
|  1|   1|    a|
|  1|   2|    a|
|  1|   3|    a|
|  1|   4|    b|
|  1|   5|    b|
|  2|   1|    b|
|  2|   2|    b|
|  2|   3|    c|
|  2|   4|    c|
|  2|   5|    c|
+---+----+-----+
```

I would like, for a **rolling** `time` window of 3, to calculate the percentage of appearances of all the values, in the `value` column. The operation should be done by `id`.

The output dataframe would look something like this:

```
+---+------------------+------------------+------------------+
| id|            perc_a|            perc_b|            perc_c|
+---+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|  1|               1.0|               0.0|               0.0|
|  1|0.6666666666666666|0.3333333333333333|               0.0|
|  1|0.3333333333333333|0.6666666666666666|               0.0|
|  2|               0.0|0.6666666666666666|0.3333333333333333|
|  2|               0.0|0.3333333333333333|0.6666666666666666|
|  2|               0.0|               0.0|               1.0|
+---+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Explanation of result:

- for `id=1`, and the **first** window of (`time=[1,2,3]`), the `value` column contains only `a`s. so the `perc_a` equals `100`, and the rest is `0`.
- for id=1, and the second window of (`time=[2,3,4]`), the `value` column contains 2 `a`s and 1 `b`, so the `perc_a` equals `66.6` the `perc_b` is `33.3` and the `perc_c` equals `0`
- etc

How could I achieve that in pyspark ?

**EDIT**
I am using pyspark 2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use count with a window function.

```py
w = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('time').rowsBetween(Window.currentRow, 2)

df = (df.select('id', F.col('time').alias('window'), 
                *[(F.count(F.when(F.col('value') == x, 'value')).over(w)
                   /
                   F.count('value').over(w) * 100).alias(f'perc_{x}')
                  for x in ['a', 'b', 'c']])
      .filter(F.col('time') < 4))
```

Comment: result looks different for id = 2, are you doing different calculation here (different window size for 2)?  id = 2's first 3 rows are b,b,c and perc_b says 100.

Answer (score 1):

Clever answer by @Emma. Expanding the answer with a `SparkSQL` implementation.

The approach is to collect values over the intended sliding row range i.e `ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 2 FOLLOWING` & filtering on `time < 4` , further exploding the collected list to count the individual frequency , and finally pivoting it to the intended format

#### SparkSQL - Collect List

```
foo = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2],
                    'time': [1,2,3,4,5, 1,2,3,4,5],
                    'value': ['a','a','a','b','b', 'b','b','c','c','c']})

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(foo)

sparkDF.registerTempTable("INPUT")

sql.sql("""
SELECT
    id,
    time,
    value,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time
                    ) as window_map,
    COLLECT_LIST(value) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time
                       ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 2 FOLLOWING
                    ) as collected_list
FROM INPUT
""").show()

+---+----+-----+----------+--------------+
| id|time|value|window_map|collected_list|
+---+----+-----+----------+--------------+
|  1|   1|    a|         1|     [a, a, a]|
|  1|   2|    a|         2|     [a, a, b]|
|  1|   3|    a|         3|     [a, b, b]|
|  1|   4|    b|         4|        [b, b]|
|  1|   5|    b|         5|           [b]|
|  2|   1|    b|         1|     [b, b, c]|
|  2|   2|    b|         2|     [b, c, c]|
|  2|   3|    c|         3|     [c, c, c]|
|  2|   4|    c|         4|        [c, c]|
|  2|   5|    c|         5|           [c]|
+---+----+-----+----------+--------------+
```

#### SparkSQL - Explode - Frequency Calculation

```
immDF = sql.sql(
    """
    SELECT
        id,
        time,
        exploded_value,
        COUNT(*) as value_count
    FROM (
            SELECT
                id,
                time,
                value,
                window_map,
                EXPLODE(collected_list) as exploded_value
            FROM (
                SELECT
                    id,
                    time,
                    value,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time
                                    ) as window_map,
                    COLLECT_LIST(value) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time
                                       ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 2 FOLLOWING
                                    ) as collected_list
                FROM INPUT
            )
            WHERE window_map < 4 <--> Filtering List where values are less than 3
    )
    GROUP BY 1,2,3
    ORDER BY id,time
    ;
    """
)

immDF.registerTempTable("IMM_RESULT")

immDF.show()

+---+----+--------------+-----------+
| id|time|exploded_value|value_count|
+---+----+--------------+-----------+
|  1|   1|             a|          3|
|  1|   2|             b|          1|
|  1|   2|             a|          2|
|  1|   3|             a|          1|
|  1|   3|             b|          2|
|  2|   1|             b|          2|
|  2|   1|             c|          1|
|  2|   2|             b|          1|
|  2|   2|             c|          2|
|  2|   3|             c|          3|
+---+----+--------------+-----------+
```

#### SparkSQL - Pivot

```
sql.sql("""
SELECT
    id,
    time,
    ROUND(NVL(a,0),2) as perc_a,
    ROUND(NVL(b,0),2) as perc_b,
    ROUND(NVL(c,0),2) as perc_c
FROM IMM_RESULT
PIVOT (
        MAX(value_count)/3 * 100.0
        FOR exploded_value IN ('a'
                                ,'b'
                                ,'c'
                            )
    )
""").show()


+---+----+------+------+------+
| id|time|perc_a|perc_b|perc_c|
+---+----+------+------+------+
|  1|   1| 100.0|   0.0|   0.0|
|  1|   2| 66.67| 33.33|   0.0|
|  1|   3| 33.33| 66.67|   0.0|
|  2|   1|   0.0| 66.67| 33.33|
|  2|   2|   0.0| 33.33| 66.67|
|  2|   3|   0.0|   0.0| 100.0|
+---+----+------+------+------+
```